# React native element Icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons, font-awesome

this is how i implement my icons

```
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
<Icon
            raised
            name="search"
            type="font-awesome"
            color={focused ? "#f1ce72" : "grey"}
            size={20}
          />
```

I want to use font-awesome type icons but I can't find a complete icon list. because when I go to the font-awesome site and I enter the name of the icon in the name property it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react-native) now has an official React Native component that's available for all who want to use the icons in their React Native projects.

[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome)

#### Get started

This package is for integrating with React Native. If you aren't using React Native then it's not going to help you. Head over to our "Get Started" page for some guidance.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started

#### Learn about our new SVG implementation

This package, under the hood, uses SVG with JS and the @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core library. This implementation differs drastically from the web fonts implementation that was used in version 4 and older of Font Awesome. You might head over there to learn about how it works.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-javascript-core

### Installation

```
$ npm i --save react-native-svg # **
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome
```

** `create-react-native-app` uses Expo, which bundles `react-native-svg`. So if you're using `create-react-native-app` you shouldn't try to add `react-native-svg`. At the time of writing, `create-react-native-app` bundles `react-native-svg` version 6, which does not include support for SVG features such as `Mask`. In order to make use of `Mask`, make sure your dependencies have `react-native-svg` 7. The example app in this repo demonstrates.

If you are using a bare react-native-cli project, run the following command to complete the setup on iOS.

```
$ cd ios && pod install
```

### Usage

You can use Font Awesome icons in your React Native components as simply as this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
```

[Visit source of text for more information (required!)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome)